# Applet with JavaFX MediaPlayer: Could not create MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx

im writing an (normal) Applet with the JavaFX MediaPlayer and get errors while instantiating the MediaPlayer object.
My first attemd was to create the Media object with the AccessController and then creating the MediaPlayer.

```
Media media = AccessController.doPrivileged(new ProxyNewMedia(path));
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Doing so I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at player.Player.start(Player.java:51)
    at gui.listener.recording.ListenerOpenPlayer$1.run(ListenerOpenPlayer.java:55)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
```

path has this format: file:/C:/Users/.../video.mp4

I also tried to create the MediaPlayer with the AccessController, but doing so I get the following Exception in an infinity loop:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$CacheContainer.getInlineStyleSelector(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$CacheContainer.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$Cache.getStyleMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$Cache.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.findMatchingStyles(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.createStyleHelper(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.